# Too Many Connections; db connect in a function

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm currently updating my PHP knowledge and I've stumbled upon a problem whilst grabbing data from my database.

The problem I have in itself could probably be sorted with the max_connection setting (yes, I've searched around), but I believe it might be a work-around, since I don't want to change base settings, if not so needed.

I have three "steps" in my little "ladder";
My main is a ladder, every ladder has one (or more) step and every step has one (or more) modules.

So what I'm trying to do is a function that retrieves all of these and shows them. Now, every function has a connection to my database; where the function runs its query and then closes. My first clue was to close the database between every function, which I did - but since I'm retrieving my code "all at once", this doesn't work (see code).

How would I go about making one database connection (maybe in a function) and calling it once, and then retrieving all the information, without opening new connections?

I hope you have all information required to answer my questions, and I hope I'm posting this in a stack overflow way.

Thank you in advance.

P.S: Dunno if I used this code tool right, it looks structured, but it doesn't have highlights?

CODE:

```
    <?php

    echo displayResult();

    function displayResult() {

        $db = new mysqli ('localhost', 'website', 'dog', 'nplus');
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ladders';
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        $r = '';

        $r .= '<table>';

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

            $r .= '<tr>'; 
            $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->ladderID) . '</td>';


    $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->ladderName) . '</td>';
        $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->created) . '</td>';
        $r .= displayAssociateStep($row->ladderID);
        $r .= '<tr><td>&nbsp</td></tr>';

    }

    $r .= '</table>';

    $db->close();

    return $r;
}

function displayAssociateStep($ladderID) {

    $r = '';

    $db = new mysqli ('localhost', 'website', 'dog', 'nplus');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM steps WHERE ladderID = '. $ladderID ;
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $r = '';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

        $r .= '<tr>';
        $r .= '<td></td>'; 
        $r .= '<td></td>';
        $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->stepName) . '</td>';
        $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->created) . '</td>';
        $r .= '</tr>';

    }

    $db->close();

    return $r;

}



?>
```

Comment: How about creating the $db object before you use the functions ? You create it, pass it as argument to the functions (or make it global for it to be accesible to them), use the functions and then close it ? That way you have only 1 connection to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to connect to the database once, and pass it around as an argument, like so:

```
<?php

  function displayResult($db) {

    $sql = "
      SELECT *
      FROM ladders
    ";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    // ADD ERROR CHECKING HERE
    // What happens if the query fails?

    $r = '<table>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $r .= '<tr>'; 
      $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->ladderID) . '</td>';
      $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->ladderName) . '</td>';
      $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->created) . '</td>';
      $r .= '</tr>';
      $r .= displayAssociateStep($db, $row->ladderID);
      $r .= '<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    }
    $r .= '</table>';

    return $r;

  }

  function displayAssociateStep($db, $ladderID) {

    // Are you 100% certain $ladderID is always safe to use in a query?
    // Does it need escaping?
    $sql = "
      SELECT *
      FROM steps
      WHERE ladderID = $ladderID
    ";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    // ADD ERROR CHECKING HERE
    // What happens if the query fails?

    $r = '';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $r .= '<tr>';
      $r .= '<td></td>'; 
      $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->stepName) . '</td>';
      $r .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row->created) . '</td>';
      $r .= '</tr>';
    }

    return $r;

  }

  // Connect once
  $db = new mysqli ('localhost', 'website', 'dog', 'nplus');

  // Pass the connection in as an argument      
  echo displayResult($db);

  // Close the connection
  $db->close();
```

Comment: That fixed it right up! Also, nicer and cleaner code with the spans. Thanks! :)

Comment: No worries - although I have just realised that the HTML this produces won't be quite right. I think you need to add `$r .= '</tr>';` after `$r .= displayAssociateStep($db, $row->ladderID);` otherwise you have a load of un-closed table rows. Most browsers will self correct this but if you don't fix it you may find you get results you don't expect. You also need to add `colspan="4"` to the `<td>` in the final row. I have edited my code with the corrections.

Comment: Another small fix - you are actually only producing 3 columns, not 4 - if you want to see any errors in the table structure add `style="border: 1px solid #000000"` to your `<td>`s. Remember to make sure that you have an equal number of cells in each row and to close everything properly or it may not display right.

Comment: Thanks guys. I even get bonuses to my question. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I would say... pass the $db variable you got in displayResult to displayAssociateStep, as an added parameter. Then you don't need to open/close connexion in displayAssociatesStep anymore. 
Is it what you want to do?